# JSON string data display with breaks?

Tags: json, string

So I'm creating a game for work, which grabs question and answer data from a JSON file that someone helped me create. All I want to figure out, is how to make the string that is returned from the data below display with line breaks for each of the multiple choice answers:

```
{
    "question": "1",
    "text"    : "How many times has the Actuarial computer lab been moved? A. Once  B. Twice  C. Six times  D. Fifteen times",
    "answer"  : "1,1"
},
```

I've been googling for a while (lots of Stackoverflow threads) but every solution appears to be something different or slightly more complex than what I want to do.

Here is how I'm displaying the string into my div:

```
var displayDiv = $("#textdisplay");
displayDiv.text(question.text);
```

Comment: Where do you want the linebreaks? If the string in the JSON file itself has `\n` characters where you want linebreaks, you could display it in a whitespace preserving tag, such as a `<pre />`. Alternatively, you could put `<br/>`s into the string, and insert it into the div as HTML.

Comment: It would be much simpler to change your object structure so you don't have to parse it.

Comment: The solution in the Asad's comment above worked. All I had to do was add the <BR/> where I wanted the breaks, and change the call to "displayDiv.html(question.text)". Might be tedious to do, but it's simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add `<br/>` or `<p>` tags to your text in the JSON file itself. If you've got a text editor that can do regex string replacement, then you want to do something like

Find: `([ABCD]\.\s)`
Replace:  `<br/>$1`

Or if you're on a machine with `sed`, you can use

```
sed -E 's/([ABCD]\. )/<br\/>\1/g' test.txt
```

That'd be my recommendation, at least. If you can't change the JSON file, use the same Regex to add breaks in JavaScript, like so:

```
question.text.replace(/([ABCD]\. )/g, '<br/>$1')
```